# Excel formula to increment within each category

Tags: excel, formula, categories, increment

I have a column that defines the category and I am trying to calculate an increment value within each category. Is it possible to calculate it with a **formula** (not VBA) ?

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did this in Google Sheets, but I'm pretty sure Excel has `COUNTIF`

So, assuming that the first cat is A1, put this in B1:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1)
```

Then you can pull it down or double click it so it is calculated for every row you have data for.

Comment: It works same way in excel. It is what I was looking for. Thanks